# Laravel - how to get records with exact match of categories using belongsToMany relation

Tags: laravel-5.6

**Products**

-id

-title

**Categories**

-id

-name

**ProductCategories**

-Products_id

-Categories_id

what i would like to achieve is get get all the products with at least matching all selected categories (eg: [1,4,6,9] )

and skip products that has only one or more of matching categories (eg: [6,9])

my code so far ... which displays the products that are needed to skip

**relationship**

```
public function productcats()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Categories', 'ProductCategories', 'Products_id ', 'Categories_id');
    }



$cats = [1,4,6,9];



Products ::whereHas('productcats', function($query) use ($cats){
                            $query->whereIn('Categories_id', $cats );
                        })
                        ->paginate(10);
```

Comment: i got it done finally.

Answer (score 0):

```
$products = Products ::whereHas('productcats', function($query) use ($cats){
                            $query->whereIn('Categories_id', $cats )
                                  ->groupBy('Products_id')
                                  ->havingRaw( 'COUNT(Products_id) = ?', [count($cats)] );
                        })
                        ->paginate(10);
```

for any one who may need it, i got the answer with guidance from here: http://www.sergiy.ca/how-to-write-many-to-many-search-queries-in-mysql-and-hibernate/

## 3. Find all articles that are tagged with at least tag1, tag2, ..., tagn